# Ionic Android build

Tags: android, ionic-framework

[image].

Hello guys, I am getting an error when I run an Ionic app on android device though command line or using android studio. Note that if I use emulator that app runs perfectly. An image is attached

Config.xml[image]

Comment: What's the Ionic Version ? Can you show your config.xml ?

Comment: check out the config.xml